# c++ initializer list pointers

Tags: c++, constructor, initializer-list

In the code below, will the two pointers always be the same value?  I'm trying to debug a large program that has a similar construct but I'm getting two different pointers for the same type of initializer list construction.

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
  protected :
    int *_i;
  public :
    A(int *i) : _i(i) { std::cout << "A " << _i << std::endl; }
};

class B : public A {
  public :
    B(int *i) : A(i) { std::cout << "B " << _i << std::endl; }
};


int main()
{
  int i = 0;
  B b(&i);
}
```

Comment: What two pointers are you speaking about?

Comment: that snippet does not reproduce the error, and should always print the same pointer

Comment: Yes, it should print out twice the same address _i holds. Assuming you mean this.

Comment: Unless, of course, the code inside B's constructor changes it before printing. That is to say, _i will always be the same across A and B, but there's nothing stopping either one from changing it.

Comment: There's only one pointer here. Try reducing your large program to a small test case that reproduces the problem (not one like this which, presumably, doesn't).